# Instalación WordPress XAMPP e IIS

Tags: wordpress, iis, xampp

Buenos días,

Estoy configurando el servidor del cliente para subir su nueva web, realizada en WordPress.

He instalado XAMPP, cambiados los puertos de Apache y MySQL para que no entre en conflicto con IIS.

Actualmente el cliente tiene varias webs funcionando con IIS. Redirigido al directorio C:\Web . No puedo parar IIS porque dejarían de funcionar las otras webs que no debo tocar.

¿Cómo puedo entonces redirigir el dominio a XAMPP y que deje de funcionar en IIS?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Cuál de los dos servidores escucha el puerto 80?

Comment: IIS es el que escucha al puerto 80

Comment: Y por qué no simplemente creas un nuevo vhost para servirlo con IIS? Lo mismo con MySQL, por qué no migras las tablas de tu Wordpress al servidor MySQL existente?

Answer (score 0):

- Entra al ISS y elimina el sitio en cuestion
- Entra a la ruta del ISS y copia la carpeta del sitio
- entra a la ruta del xamp y pega la carpeta del sitio

> - La ruta del ISS por defecto es `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`

Lo que no entiendo muy bien es porque dices que dejaria de funcionar... porq normalmente el ISS tu te habilitas un puerto para que el sitio funcione por ese puerto.

el xamp solo trabaja por el puerto 80 (Así esta configurado). Solo es cuestión de copiar y pegar la carpeta del proyecto.

Comment: Hola,

El cliente tiene varias webs en ese servidor con IIS en el directorio C:\Web (tal como he explicado en el enunciado). Yo he subido los archivos en C:\xampp\htdocs\ con los puertos correspondientes, pero sale en localhost. Quiero saber cómo asignar ahí el dominio.

Comment: Cuando colocas localhost en el navegador a que sitio te direciona?

Answer (score 0):

Como solo existe un puerto 80 tienes tres opciones:

### Opción 1 - Dejarlo como está

Todos los sitios son atendidos por tu servidor IIS. Esta opción no requiere ningún cambio.

### Opción 2 - Usar otro puerto

El sitio en cuestión lo atiende XAMPP **en otro puerto**. Digamos que tienes tres sitios:

- `http://sitioA.com` lo atiende IIS en el puerto 80.
- `http://sitioB.com` lo atiende IIS en el puerto 80.
- `http://sitioC.com:88` lo atiende XAMPP en el puerto 88.

### Opción 3 - Usar un proxy en reversa

En este caso, instalar *un tercer* servidor web (recomiendo Nginx) que escuche el puerto 80, y al recibir una solicitud, la mande al servidor que corresponda. Los servidores IIS y XAMPP serían internos, con puertos inaccesibles desde el exterior. El proxy sería la compuerta entre el exterior y estos servidores.

- `http://sitioA.com` lo atiende IIS en el puerto 3000.
- `http://sitioB.com` lo atiende IIS en el puerto 4000.
- `http://sitioC.com` lo atiende XAMPP en el puerto 8000.

Realmente es más simple hacerlo que explicarlo y Nginx, el servidor recomendado es uno de los mejores en desempeño y características.

La configuración es algo así:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sitioa.com;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sitiob.com;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
}


server {
  listen 80;
  server_name sitioc.com;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
```

La documentación, en inglés: https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/

Comment: Ya está el XAMPP dirigido al 81 tal y como dije en la pregunta

Comment: @cluna si tienes el xampp escuchando en el puerto 81, no te funciona cargarlo como `sitio.com:81` ?